# jquery Tab - Open Link in current panel does not work

Tags: jquery, tabs

I just started playing around with the Jquery ui tabs. The content of the Tabs consist mainly of static content at the beginning.

Now some of the content within the panels do have Links to some kind of subcontent. So if the User clicks on a link in the panel I would like to replace the content of the current panel with the content coming from the link.

So I used the script directly from the jquery ui tab documentation but I can't get it to work. It is always opening the link directly, not within the panel. The code I use for testing is quite simple:

```
<div id="MyTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#TestTab1">TestTab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#TestTab2">TestTab</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="TestTab1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor. dumm di dumm
        <a href="http://mywebserver/somelink">Test</a>
    </div>
    <div id="TestTab2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor. dumm di dumm 2
        <a href="http://mywebserver/somelink2">Test 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#MyTabs').tabs({
            load: function(event, ui) {
                $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
                    $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                    return false;

                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Additionally, if I have the content of the panel loaded using an AJAX call no link within the panel is working whatsoever.

Any idea what I`m doing wrong?

Help is really appreciated

Regards

Maik

Edit1:

OK, I got a bit further. I replaced the Javascript with the following snippet:

```
        $(function() {
        $("#MyTabs").tabs();
        $("#MyTabs").bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
            AddClickHandler(ui);
        });
    });

    function AddClickHandler(ui) {
        $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
            MyAlert("AddClickHandler");
            $(ui.panel).load(this.href, AddClickHandler(ui));
            return false;
        });
    }
```

After this change all links on a panel will update the content of the current panel. So far so good. Still one problem left. I can't get it to work for subsequent links. I tried to do it with the second "AddClickHandler" for callback when the ajax call has finished. Using a different function with a simple alert showd it is actually been called when the content of the panel has been updated. But I can't bind anything to the new links in that content. The "$('a', ui.panel)..." doesn't work. What would be the correct selector for this?

Any hint?

Regards

Maik

Comment: Just to make sure, have you included the jquery.js file in your script?

Comment: yes, the jquery files are included. The Tab itself is working. It just simply opens links in the complete window, not within the current panel.

Comment: OK, I think I got further. Reading the Docs for the jquery tabs again I had to recognize that it binds to the Load event which only get`s called when the content of the tab is called on the fly. 

So if use a link in the li elements it is working for the links in the tabs. BUT only for the first content. If the content of a tab has been replaced and the new content also contains a link, how would I rebind the event to the link?

Answer (score 1):

that doesnt look right at all..

the example looks like this:

```
<div id="example">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="ahah_1.html"><span>Content 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ahah_2.html"><span>Content 2</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ahah_3.html"><span>Content 3</span></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

notice, the links are in the TABs themselves, not in the tab content

**Edit:** 
Ok, i think i see your problem. I dont see any code for you to register opening of those links within the tabs. so when the user clicks a link, it will open inside the browser window like a normal link.. anyway.

try something like this:

```
$("#MyTabs").find("a").click(function(){
   $(this).parent(".ui-tabs-panel").load(this.href);
   return false;
});
```

**Edit2:**
I just realized that your "load" function does the same thing as the function i wrote above. anyway, try my function and see if it works, if it doesm step through your function with firebug and see what is different, and if it doesnt.. step through your function with firebug.. or provide an online demo and i can look at it

**Edit3:**
Ok here is better solution:

add this function:

```
var bindAjaxLinks = function(){
    $("#MyTabs").find("a").click(function(){
         $(this).parent(".ui-tabs-panel").load(this.href, {}, bindAjaxLinks);
         return false;
    });
}

//in the tabs constructor add the select function:

$("#MyTabs").tabs({select: function(event, ui) {
   bindAjaxLinks();
  },
  //your other stuff
 }
```

probably not the best solution, since it will rebind the click function to all links every time a link is opened. but probably ok for now, unless you are building some production site

Comment: No, this part is ok and working. There are a couple ways of using the Tabs. Your example is loading the content of each panel on the fly. I want to have the initial content already within the tabs. And them update the content of some panels depending on the links the user clicks within each panel (e.g. I have a list of items within one panel and would like to edit or add one). 
And the code for the tab themselve is working. Look at the example on this link: http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/default.html

Comment: i added a solution to my response. you might want to refine it by assigning a class to links which will open in current tab, and find those instead of all links.

Comment: Your code seems to be a good first step. I can now at least click a link on the first panel and it opens the content within the panel. But it does not work for links on other panels. And if the just loaded content contains another link it will open again in the full window.

I just wonder why this doesn't work. The javascript part comes 1-to-1 from the jquery documentation. So I assume I`m making a stupid error somwhere.

Comment: it probably is a stupid error =) but i dont know enough about tabs to help you with it, i just used them for the first time the other day myself.

Comment: ok, good luck, i hope my code helps you. i am leaving for the day

Answer (score 0):

you can use live() as follows:

```
$("#myTabs").tabs({
        load: function(event, ui) {
         $("#myTabs").find("a").live('click', function() {
        $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
}})
```